# Python3 - read from unflushed buffer from other exe

Tags: python, c++, debugging, stream, filestream

I have an application written in C++ which write to an ofstream (file output stream).
The problem is, that the C++-Application is writing about 2'000 Lines before flushing the stream (*<< endl*) and the output became visible inside the file (which i monitor via *tail -f*). But for debugging purpose i want to see the *unflushed content* of the stream.

Adding *<< endl* inside the C++-Application sounds logic, but isn't possible at all because there are too many places where i have to add *<< endl* and it is going to look really ugly because i have to add

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
fileStream << endl;
#endif
```

everywhere in the code.

So i'm looking for a way to read the stream from another application.
I have read many stackoverflow articles, including [Reading from flushed vs unflushed buffers](Reading from flushed vs unflushed buffers) and many others.
But i can only find answers where the second application is called as an subprocess inside the Python-Script via

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("a.out", **stdout=subprocess.PIPE**)
```

and redirect the stdout to an pipe.
But in my case i wont redirect the stdout to a pipe from a subprocess, i want to read from an unflushed buffer.
Is there a way to do this with Python 3?

Comment: You want a Python script to access the contents of a C++ program's file buffer? That sounds hard! (And OS-specific). And it's probably not a good idea: such buffers should be treated as black boxes. Even the C++ program itself shouldn't attempt to access its own buffers. In C it's not recommended, and I expect that C++ is even more strict.

Comment: (cont) From the [GNU libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) "While the array remains a stream buffer, the stream I/O functions will use the buffer for their internal purposes. You shouldn’t try to access the values in the array directly while the stream is using it for buffering".

Comment: one of my my thoughts was to flush the buffer from external. I know that sounds hard and OS-specific.